# Spring MVC with Thymeleaf + Bootstrap using webjars

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring project where I included the following webjars into `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.7-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I included in my HTML view the following link and scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />

<script src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```

But it didn't work, no mapping found:

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-15) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestPublicWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'testapp'
```

...so I tried to include the following mapping into `servlet.xml`:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

But with this, mapping for my `/TestApplication` is not found:

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-13) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestApplication/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'testapp'
```

How should webjars be included in a Spring project in a correct way?

Answer (score 23):

The problem is that you are mixing the standard HTML `href` tag with Thymeleaf's syntax `@{}`. Change it as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />

<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```

And if you are using Spring Security you need also specify the authorization to your webjars in the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method like:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll();
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple things I could think of as to why the above is not working for you. Make sure you are using spring mvc namespace inside of your servlet.xml file. Looks something like:

```
<bean xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"....
```

Also not sure why you are trying to access assets using `@{..}` when you have specified the classpath. Try removing the `@{..}` like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```